# Blank lines of unknown origin when running vim after tput clear

Tags: debian, vim, gnome-terminal

I have a rather bizarre issue with terminal behaviour. If I execute `tput clear` to clear the screen, my cursor (as expected) goes to the top of the terminal.

If I run `vi` after that (`vim` actually), when it exits there are some blank lines before the next prompt. When I do that normally, the prompt simply shows up at the next line. The following shows a transcript after `tput clear` and running `vi` twice (simply exiting each time):

```
+--------------------------+
|pax> vi                   |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|pax> vi                   |
|pax>                      |
:                          :
+--------------------------+
```

As you can see, the first execution left three blank lines between the prompts, the second left none.

Other terminal manipulation style programs like `less` don't exhibit this behaviour. There's nothing the least bit suspicious in my `PS1` prompt variable, it's simply set to `"pax> "` with absolutely no funny characters or escape sequences. What could be causing it?

Environment: running Debian 7.3 (from `/etc/debian_version`), vim 7.3 (from `vim --version`), Gnome Terminal 3.4.1.1 (from `gnome-terminal --version`), `uname -a` output of:

```
Linux paxbox01 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.51-1 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

For emulation issues, it's the version of the vte library that really matters. It received many relevant fixes around version 0.36; I'm afraid you're using an older one.